# Symmetric cryptography key exchange

Tags: cryptography, encryption-symmetric, diffie-hellman, symmetric-key

I am using AES for encryption on a java system and decrypting it back on a javascript platform. What is the best way for a secure key exchange over such system ?

Comment: There is no "best way". It depends on the use case, attack scenarios etc. If the Java Script is in the browser I would use TLS for the key exchange, and then use the key within the TLS protocol :)

Comment: Relevant: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Comment: Take @owlstead's advice, don't do it. Just use SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 0):

As @owlstead said, there is no such thing as "best way": analyze your security and performance requirements and choose a well-tried protocol as SSL/TLS.

Note: AES is indeed a symmetric crypto-system, for key exchange we usually start with an asymmetric protocol to agree on a symmetric key. Then this key is used to protect the following communication with a symmetric protocol.

Comment: I am planning to use Diffie-Hellman key exchange for the symmetric key transfer. Any suggestions regarding that ?

Comment: It is a good idea [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/KeyAgreement.html) might help.